# How to detect if a URL fires upon loading a page

Tags: testing, selenium-rc

We're trying to validate if a URL fires upon loading a web page. Is there a way to do this programmatically using Selenium RC? The event does not appear within the page HTML or DOM.

Thanks.

Comment: Scenario - If you navigate to http://www.architecturaldigest.com, with the Net console in Firebug enabled, you will notice a bunch of URLs being fired (e.g. tag.admeld.com) that are visible in firebug, but not in the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selenium.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true");` enables the 'capture' of all the HTTP requests/responses associated with the loading of the web page. Once formatted, these results can be reported easily.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify the URL as part of your test? 
If so, then what about running a httpd server and checking if it gets a hit when your page loads?

Comment: Hmmm...Not sure I understand. Are you saying that in the scenario above, I'd check admeld.com, to see if a 'hit' was registered based on my request? Ideally, I'd like to do this programmatically within the browser itself. These hits are visible in the Net console of Firebug. Any way, I could transfer the Net panel results in a browser, and then simply assert the presence of these "hidden" urls?

Comment: No, you don't check admeld.com, you run the http server locally, so you are checking localhost. You can do it programmatically, but you will need to branch out a bit by starting a http server, then tracking events such as page requests to that http server.

Comment: I'm not sure if asserting the presence of a url is the same as checking the urls get fired.

Comment: Agreed. Though at this stage, I'm only required to assert the presence of these "hidden" URLs. Thanks.